# Function to orbit point of view with glut oscilates instead

Tags: c++, glut

I am back to c++ programming after many years and anyway there was only a couple of modules at university my experience.. So please be patient..

I am tryng to orbit point of view around the center with the following function:

```
void Orbit(Mundo* m)
{
    float d = sqrt((m->camposx * m->camposx) + (m->camposz * m->camposz));
    float theta = ((atan2(m->camposx, m->camposz)) * 180) / PI;
    theta += 1;
    float thetarad = theta * 3.14159 / 180;
    m->camposx = d*cos(thetarad);
    m->camposz = d*sin(thetarad);
}
```

But instead of that what is that is oscillates between the original point and the first increment. That os, moves as it should but then comes back..

I am pretty sure that I am doing somehting wrong with the function but I paste here the relevant bits of the code just in case.

Previously I have declared:

```
struct Mundo
{
    float camposx;
    float camposy;
    float camposz;
};
```

and instanced:

```
Mundo mundo = {50, 50, 50};
```

and recalled:

```
void OnDraw(void){

.....
gluLookAt ( mundo.camposx, mundo.camposy, mundo.camposz,  // posicion del ojo   
        0.0, 0, 0.0,      // hacia que punto mira  (0,0,0)    
        0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
.....
}

void OnTimer(int value) 
{ 
.....
Orbit(&mundo);
.....
}
```

I know I am not using classes yet, I am following a tutorial and this is one of the first lessons. Clases are introduced next chapter. Also, there are some claculations could be done more straight forward but I am just making things clear for now.

Any help much appreciated. Thank you!

PS: I tried with debugging but when it comes to the following lines it stops and ask for some location of the .dll file and not sure what to do..

```
void OnTimer(int value) 
{ 
....
    glutTimerFunc(1000,OnTimer,0);  
    glutPostRedisplay(); 
....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When I switch arguments of atan2 it does not oscillate. So your math is somehow wrong.

On XY-plane if P=(x=10, y=1) then the angle should be few degrees. Your atan2(x,y) gives arctan(10)= 84deg. atan2(y,x) = arctan(1/10) = 5 deg.